# PHP isset show on button click

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I have `edit.php` file in which I have multiple `if(isset($_POST[]))` clauses.

I have an if clause `if(isset($_POST["view"]))` which displays a row from database and another one `if(isset($_POST["edit"]))` which can edit many rows  (number of rows is send via html post method).

Is it possible to implement a button which once clicked would show the content of `if(isset($_POST["edit"]))`?

Comment: Without page refresh you can use AJAX. Or with a page refresh just use a `form`.

Comment: create the entire thing inside a `<form>`, and use the submit button with `name='edit'` for re-sending the request to same page and you'll be able to check `if(isset($_POST["edit"]))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<form action="welcome.php" method="post">
View: <input type="text" name="view"><br>
Edit: <input type="text" name="edit"><br>
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp

in your welcome.php file:

```
echo $_POST["view"];
echo $_POST["edit"];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
var sampledata="Hello";
showdata() {
  // your place to load the data, eg, from preloaded array or via ajax
  var data=sampledata;

  // if preloaded render those data into (using ajax requires to add another function)
  document.getElementById("output").innerHTML="<B>"+data+"</B>";
}
</script>

<form action="welcome.php" method="post">
<div id="output"></div>
<input type="button" onclick="showdata()"><br>
</form>
```